# Mongo Driver Update using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

```
$bulk->update(['name' => 'a', 'numner' => 4],['$set' => ['number' => 3]],['multi' => true, 'upsert' => false]);
```

This being the syntax for updating a record, am trying to pass an object which has values for filter predicate and set like the following,

```
$bulk->update($filter,$set,['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false]);
```

where, `$filter` holds `stdClass Object ( [name] => xyz [number] => 5 )` as value

and `$set` holds `stdClass Object ( [dd] => l )` as value

It's not updating any document using this method. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Try using array, rather than std object.

```
$query_array = json_decode(json_encode($query_std_object), True);
$set_array = json_decode(json_encode($set_std_object), True);

$bulk->update($query_array,$set_array,array('multi' => true, 'upsert' => false);
```

Comment: My collection has a field named 'numner' too(initially created by mistake). The concern is to pass an array object as filter predicate and set value

Comment: Okay, Try running these two queries directly on the mongo shell, and check the output, where you are able to query, and might be it is not working in shell as well(may something wrong in query,like query a string type with int):

`db.collection_name.find({'name' : 'a', 'numner' : 4})`
and
`db.collection_name.update({'name' : 'a', 'numner' : 4} , {'$set' : {'number' : 3 } , {'multi' : true, 'upsert' : false})`

Comment: It works completely fine in shell as well as from php when am explicitly specifying the condition and set values. But the same time when am passing the query conditions as object it is not working(documentation says the data type for query and set is array object)

Comment: Rather than passing std obj array, try passing array only in find and set query.
I have edited the answer, to include that one.

Comment: And if it doesn't work, also share your PHP version and mongo driver and library version

Comment: have tried all array, std object and array object values as input. It's not working

Comment: Mongo 4.0.0
PHP 7.1.0